# Parsing just time to get difference

Tags: java, datetime, parsing, time, java-time

I am trying to simplify my life parsing logs and gathering times. I get a file with the log statements that all start with the time stamp in this format

```
16:08:39.660
```

I want to turn this string into a just a simple time that I can get the difference between the two in either seconds or milliseconds. I have been looking on here and it was suggested to use

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.sss");
Date start = format.parse(startTimeString);
Date end = format.parse(endTimeString);

long difference = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
```

This however is giving me totally different times. For example, 16:08:39.660
was giving me 4:19. Because the times were wrong, it was giving me negative differences, which is impossible for my given context. How can I turn

```
16:08:39.660
16:08:52.452
```

into a difference of `12.792`?

Comment: For [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) the `s` (lower case) stands for seconds. That means `ss.sss` is saying `seconds.seconds`. Assuming the numbers after the `.` are milliseconds the correct letter is `S` (upper case).

Comment: Thank you @Slaw. Great catch! that fixed it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It doesn’t directly answer your question, but I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See the second half of [Sun’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51969384/5772882).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `SSS` for milliseconds, thy this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

A better approach is using `java.time.LocalTime` and `java.time.Duration` if you are working with java 8+, so you don't have to write the pattern:

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse("16:08:39.660");
LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse("16:08:52.452");
Duration duration = Duration.between(start, end);

System.out.println(duration.toMillis()); // 12792
System.out.println(duration.toMillis() / 1000.00); // 12.792
System.out.println(duration.toSeconds()); // 12
```

Comment: Would love to like this 100 times. Thank you!

Comment: Plus one for suggesting using `java.time`.